# Read internal table - field symbol has not been assigned yet

Tags: abap, sap-erp, internal-tables

I have wrote this small piece of code which updates the data in `it_alv` based on values in another internal table `it_alv_to_check`.

At some point while executing the code in the `ELSE` statement block, I got the error:

> field symbol has not been assigned yet

But I had it at first assigned dynamically using `READ TABLE` statement.

How to make sure that even if `sy-subrc <> 0`, the field symbol will be assigned?

```
 FIELD-SYMBOLS: <to_check> LIKE LINE OF it_alv.

   LOOP AT it_alv ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_alv_2>).
      READ TABLE it_alv_to_check ASSIGNING <to_check>  WITH KEY belnr = <fs_alv_2>-belnr.
      IF sy-subrc = 0.
        <fs_alv_2>-statement_year = <to_check>-statement_year.
        <fs_alv_2>-laufi = <to_check>-laufi.
        <fs_alv_2>-user_field_1 = <to_check>-user_field_1.
        <fs_alv_2>-stceg = <to_check>-stceg.
        <fs_alv_2>-name1 = <to_check>-name1.
        <fs_alv_2>-monat_from = <to_check>-monat_from.
      ELSE.
        <fs_alv_2>-statement_year = <to_check>-statement_year.
        <fs_alv_2>-laufi = <to_check>-laufi.
        <fs_alv_2>-user_field_1 = <to_check>-user_field_1.
        <fs_alv_2>-stceg = <to_check>-stceg.
        <fs_alv_2>-name1 = <to_check>-name1.
        <fs_alv_2>-monat_from = <to_check>-monat_from.
        <fs_alv_2>-color = VALUE #( ( color-col = 6
                        color-int = 0
                        color-inv = 1
                        )
                         ).
      ENDIF.
    ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: The code you have posted has intrinsically no possibility to fail, as far as I can see, but this piece of code cannot be tested as it contains many syntax errors like `it_alv` and `it_alv_to_check` are not declared, etc. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that people can understand what you are talking about. Mark that it should be both minimal and reproducible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have your field-symbol assigned in this scenario. You read an internal table using `READ TABLE` statement and in case the **entry was found** with the given key (i.e. `sy-subrc = 0`), the found table row is **assigned to a field symbol** and the field symbol points to the table row in the memory.

Otherwise, if **no table row is found**, you have no entry to assign field-symbol to, and the **field symbol remains unchanged or initial**. In this case you cannot rely on it being assigned (it can be assigned but point to the wrong entry) or assume the assignment itself (remains initial because it was not previously assigned).

More about it: [READ TABLE, result ... ASSIGNING](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-us/abapread_table_outdesc.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_2@2@)

Depending on what you want to achieve you can assign some default values in the else branch or implement some other logic to handle this scenario.

Comment: Initial task is to update it_alv based on values of another internal table, the structure of both tables are the same. it_alv_to_check has more values (50k), it_alv has 4k. For matching values in BELNR i want to update values of the fields written in code, so far i tried what you can see. I try to avoid double looping at best.

Comment: If you want to update values of the fields only for matching entries with BELNR, than IF ... block might be enough, you may not need ELSE branch at all.
But as you've got into the else branch, than there is an entry which does not exist in it_alv_to_check table - you might set a breakpoint to check exactly what is being check and if your assumptions are correct.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that those internal tables are without a header so I am not sure how am i supposed to assign data from it_alv_check to it_alv for lines that BELNR does not match within that piece of code. This is why i tried with IF/ELSE statement. I guess I could just loop at it_alv_check and pass it to structure with header line and then check if the belnr is equal but that would be a double loop if i am not missing something.

Comment: It has nothing to do with header lines, which just create an explicit work area for the table and are considered obsolete.

You cannot assign something which is not existing: you try to find the entry in internal table which matches some criteria. If something is found - you can assign a  pointer to it. But if nothing is found - you cannot assign a pointer to nowhere, or better to say you cannot use a pointer assigned to nowhere - this is an error you got.

Comment: Yes i do understand now what is the problem in this case, i  was wondering what diffrent logic imlement here. Maybe LOOP AT GROUP BY will do the thing ? I use it so far to group values within one internal table, if it's possible to use it between 2 tables that should resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

What your code appears to be doing is:

1. If a corresponding row is found it_alv_to_check, take the values of that row to overwrite various values in it_alv.
2. If no corresponding row is found in it_alv_to_check, then also take those values (from the row that does not exist!) and write them into it_alv. And also set the color to a fixed value.

The first part of the second point is obviously impossible. You can not do something with data which does not exist. This just does not make sense on a basic logical level.

So what you need to do here first is some conceptual work. What exactly do you expect to happen with the values statement_year, laufi, user_field_1, stceg, name1 and monat_from in the row of `it_alv` when `it_alv_to_check` does not contain a row for that `belnr`? Leave them as they are? Fill them with fixed placeholder data? Fill them with values from a *different* row, and if so which one?

Answer this question (probably with the help of the person who gave you this requirement) and the answer to your actual question will probably appear on its own. If not, feel free to ask a new question where you describe what exactly you want to happen and what you need to know in order to do that.

Answer (score -2):

I've changed declaring of the field symbol to:

```
READ TABLE it_alv_to_check ASSIGNING FIELD SYMBOL(<to_check>)  WITH KEY belnr = <fs_alv_2>-belnr.
```

and now it works fine

Comment: It doesn't matter, because the logic is the same - if entry is not existing it cannot be found, no difference which way search for it. In this case the declaration of the field symbol is inside read table statement, but it does not influence the logic or the result of looking for a record. As you did not post the whole working code it is not possible to say what is the reason and what else did you change.